# Bundling a WSL distribution that is managed by my Windows application

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm writing a Windows application that interacts with a WSL distribution/instance which has Docker running.  Also, in some cases, my application will also run commands/processes directly in the WSL/Linux distribution.

I would like for that WSL distribution to be "managed" by my application.  By that, I mean that:

1. The distribution should be installed by my application so that users don't have to have knowledge of WSL itself.  If the users have to install the WSL distribution themselves, it's entirely possible that they could misconfigure it.  It's also possible that some users might not be able to get it up and running in the first place.
2. The user should have no control over my application's managed WSL distribution.  They would not be able to:

   - Shutdown the instance when it is running under my application.
   - Uninstall the instance without uninstalling my application.
   - Preferably the user would not even see the distribution at all.

*Can I create/install a distribution that is managed by my application in this way?*

It's obvious that I could simply run a batch script, import the instance, and then just run it like that. But this seems verbose and, as mentioned, would still be visible to the end user.

Comment: Just noticed that I'd never replied to your question (which closing out some old browser tabs).  I did spend some time considering options for it, but I can't think of any way to reliably "hide"/manage a WSL distribution for the user.  They'll always have access to it.  You *might* could do something similar with a managed VM in Hyper-V -- It appears that WSL and BlueStacks both install/manage/hide VMs.  I believe this is done with Hyper-V "partitioning" (not to be confused with disk partitioning), but I can find no documentation on how to do it.

Comment: I'm just wondering what the guys from docker do, because the are also leveraging WSL 2 under the hood, but I never saw a distro running. It would be really awsome if there is a way. And I guess it would be enough if the distros just don't show up if someone finds a hacky way or so the access them so be it.

Comment: Well, the `docker-desktop` and `docker-desktop-data` distributions *do* show up with the `wsl -l -v` command.  You can even launch the `docker-desktop` one (but not `-data`) and modify it, and even break things as  a result.  However, Docker Desktop installs new versions of the distribution when it upgrades, so it will (eventually) overwrite the "corrupt" version with a new, fixed one.  I don't know if Docker Desktop has a mechanism in place to detect changes to the managed distro, though, but that does give me an idea for a "maybe" answer.

Comment: Oh, thats my fault, I didn't use docker desktop in a long time, I was under the impression, that the won't show up. It's kind of "reassuring" that even docker handles it that way. Thank you very much for your input und help, I'll upvote your answer, since thats probably the best we can get at this point in time, even tough users could temper with it. Thanks again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I definitely can't offer you a direct answer that meets those requirements, and I don't think it's possible, at least not currently.

WSL distributions are always visible to the end user.  And they can always be `--terminate`'d or even `--unregister`'d.  Even Docker Desktop's distribution are subject to these limitations.

You can see the Docker Desktop distros with `wsl.exe -l -v`, returning something like:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Tumbleweed             Stopped         2
...
  Ubuntu-22.04           Running         2
  Artix-dinit            Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
...
```

<sub>side-note:  I have entirely too many distributions ;-)</sub>

But ... Docker Desktop *does* overwrite the distro with a new version when you upgrade, so any changes to it will (at least eventually) be overwritten.

So that does provide a *possibility*:

- Ship your managed distro in `tar` form in/with your application.
- When starting the application for the first time, create (`--import`) the distribution from the tarball.
- Make sure that nothing in the distribution writes to/modifies the filesystem.  You might could even set it read-only in some way, but I haven't tried that.
- Perform a checksum of the distribution `vhdx` when starting each time, and confirm that it hasn't been modified.
- If it has been modified, then delete it and re-import.

---

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, there may be a way to do this with a Hyper-V VM (but only, of course, on Windows Professional or higher).  The WSL2 VM itself is hidden and managed in some way, and the [same appears to be the case with BlueStacks](https://superuser.com/q/1616181/1210833).

I'm still not sure *how* they do this.  From watching the Event Viewer, it appears that a new Hyper-V "Partition" is created when starting WSL2.  This does not appear to be related to any "disk partitioning", so I believe that it is some type of Hyper-V partition that is hidden from the user.